# Compute Using modular arithmetic for the decimal byte ring,

Tags: modular-arithmetic

```
Using modular arithmetic for the decimal byte ring,  

Compute: 5 + (- 175+222)*13 =
```

This is a question I'm supposed to understand before I start a assembly language course next semester. Can someone break down the steps in getting the anwser? I assume there is more here than basic PEMDOS math.

I'm having a difficult time finding a understandable resource online for modular arithmetic on decimal byte rings. Perhaps I should just be looking at one or the other..?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "decimal byte rings"? Is your problem above using some modulus which you did not show?

Comment: In an assembler context it would make some sense to understand "byte ring" as the ring of integers modulo 256. But "decimal byte ring" is a strange specification -- the integers modulo 256 is _the same ring_ no matter whether we notate the representatives in decimal or something else (hexadecimal? binary?)

Comment: Still, however, even "byte ring" with the meaning I suggest above is far from standard terminology. Pray tell, _where_ did you find this "decimal byte ring" wording?

Comment: @Azmoti  This is all of the instruction I was given by my soon to be professor..

Comment: @Henning
My assumption, which may not be correct, is that if 'decimal' does not matter, then it was just put in there to ensure we understand that it doesn't matter if we use a different base. there were a couple unrelated problems of a different subject where he unnecessarily stated the base of a number which made no difference in the anwser.

Comment: @user54638: Does that answer your question, then, or do you need an explanation of arithmetic modulo 256?

Comment: I have heard of byte-ring buffers for storing data - which means they throw stuff out when full and use a ring structure to do so. My guess is that what this means. The operation above would then just be 616 and would be shown using assembly language instructions.

Comment: @Henning An explanation would be nice. I'm trying to read up about it now but having some trouble with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment thread, I believe that "the decimal byte ring" must mean arithmetic modulo 256.

This is the same as ordinary arithmetic *except* you take all operands, intermediate and final results mod 256. Therefore

$$ 5 + (-175+222)\times 13 = 5 + (81+222)\times 13 $$
because $-175 \bmod 256 = 81$ (in contrast to the remainder operator of many programming languages the modulus operation always produces a number between 0 and 255);

$$ \cdots = 5 + 47 \times 13 $$
because $81+222=303$ and $303 \bmod 256=47$;

$$ \cdots = 5 + 99 $$
because $47\times 13 = 611$ and $611\bmod 256=99$;

$$ \cdots = 104 $$
which is itself mod 256.

---

Now, instead of this we could *also* just use ordinary arithmetic and take mod 256 once and for all at the end:

$$5+(-175+222)\times 13 = 5+47\times 13 = 5+611 = 616$$
and then $616\bmod 256=104$ again. This works because of the general rules
$$ (a\bmod N)+(b\bmod N) \bmod N = (a+b)\bmod N$$
$$ (a\bmod N)-(b\bmod N) \bmod N = (a-b)\bmod N$$
$$ (a\bmod N)(b\bmod N) \bmod N = ab\bmod N$$
In practice one will often just reduce mod 256 at strategic places in the computation where the intermediate results would get impractically large otherwise.

**Division** is not defined modulo 256.

---

The reason why this is relevant is that we can think of it as arithmetic on numbers where we only remember the bottommost 8 bits of the binary representation. This happens fairly often in practice when we do arithmetic on 32- or 64-bit values but then only *store* 8 bits of the result in order to save space. Each combination of 8 remembered bits *conceptually* represents all the infinitely many integers that end with those 8 bits; we *represent* this infinite set of numbers with the one it would have been if the forgotten bits were all zeroes.

The reason why division is not allowed is that it would bring some of the forgotten bits into view, and then the result would not be well-defined.